# Another differentiation question

Tags: derivatives

$f=\frac{y'(x)^2}{x^3} dx$

I don't understand how to take the derivative if y is some unknown function. Could someone solve step by step?

Answer (score 0):

Assume f(x) = y(x)^2/x^3. Use quotient rule and the chainrule: f'(x) = (2yy'x^3 - 3x^2y^2)/x^6 = 2yy'/x^3 - 6y^2/x^4.

Comment: and replace $y$ by $y'$ and $y'$ by $y''$.